# Эффект гармошки в меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер, есть js код который при наведении на элемент списка, показывает подменю.
Но если быстро выводить и убирать мышку с пределов блока , то получается эффект гармошки, меню выполняет столько полных циклов кода, столько я раз сделал.
Как запретить выполнение кода, пока прошлый раз не закончился?

```js
function dropDownMenu() {
  $(this).children('img').toggleClass('chevron-rotate');
  $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').slideToggle(250);
}

$('.dropdown-li').on({
  mouseenter: dropDownMenu,
  mouseleave: dropDownMenu
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-li">
    <a href="#">О нас</a>
    <img src="img/chevron-white.png" alt="">
    <ul class="dropdown-ul">
      <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Мероприятия</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Сертификаты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Награды</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Вопрос-ответ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-li">
    <a href="#">Программы</a>
    <img src="img/chevron-white.png" alt="">
    <ul class="dropdown-ul">
      <li><a href="#">Для похудения</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Для здоровья</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

---

я попробовал написать условие с использованием флагов, но не помогло. С js работаю совсем недавно, не могу понять чего не работает

```
function dropDownMenu() {
    var flag = true;
    if (flag){
        $(this).children('img').addClass('chevron-rotate');
        $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').slideToggle(250);
        var flag = false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).children('img').removeClass('chevron-rotate');
        $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').slideToggle(250);
        var flag = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше, наверное, остановить предыдущую анимацию.

```
function dropDownMenu() {
  $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').stop();
  $(this).children('img').toggleClass('chevron-rotate');
  $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').slideToggle(250);
}
```

<strike>С флагом</strike> (работает плохо):

```
var sliding = false;
function dropDownMenu() {
  if (!sliding) {
    sliding = true;
    $(this).children('img').toggleClass('chevron-rotate');
    $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').slideToggle(250, function(){ sliding = false; });
  }
}
```

```js
function dropDownMenu() {
  $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').stop();
  $(this).children('img').toggleClass('chevron-rotate');
  $(this).children('.dropdown-ul').slideToggle(250);
}

$('.dropdown-li').on({
  mouseenter: dropDownMenu,
  mouseleave: dropDownMenu
})
```

```css
.dropdown-ul
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-li">
    <a href="#">О нас</a>
    <img src="img/chevron-white.png" alt="">
    <ul class="dropdown-ul">
      <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Мероприятия</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Сертификаты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Награды</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Вопрос-ответ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-li">
    <a href="#">Программы</a>
    <img src="img/chevron-white.png" alt="">
    <ul class="dropdown-ul">
      <li><a href="#">Для похудения</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Для здоровья</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: я попробовал написать условие с использованием флагов, но не помогло. С js работаю совсем недавно, не могу понять чего не работает

Comment: а возможно сделать, что бы при убирании мышки, меню вызванное наведением пряталось, а то они друг на друга наезжают немного
(http://prntscr.com/is6lf9)

Comment: @Толик Пора задавать вопрос с примером кода и разметки - обратите внимание на кнопку "Фрагмент кода ..."  в редакторе вопроса.